# Unidentified LLDB behavior in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, lldb

So I just updated to Android Studio 2.2 and I'm having problems running my app on my device. What seems to happen is that now there are two separate debuggers running when I try to debug my app. One of them is the good old Java debugger and the other one is I think the LLDB debugger.

My app has a splash screen which is presented as the first `Activity` in the app. What happened before was the splash screen would only be shown around 1 second before the actual intro screen showed up. After I updated my Android Studio to version 2.2, it takes around a minute before the splash screen disappears.

I put a breakpoint to the `SplashScreenActivity.onCreate()` to see if everything was OK. After I launch the app, it waits for some time before the LLDB debugger stops with a SIGURG signal. I click resume program and again it hits the same signal. This happens 7-8 times, after which my breakpoint in `SplashScreenActivity.onCreate()` is hit by the Java debugger. After this, the app keeps working normal.

I don't know if it helps but the console of the LLDB debugger is like this:

```
09/26 00:19:32: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\Documents\SourceTree\autocolorsplash-android\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android
$ adb shell am start -n "com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android/com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android.activities.SplashScreenActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android | com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android | com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android.test
Connecting to com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android
Now Launching Native Debug Session
Starting LLDB server: /data/data/com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh /data/data/com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android/lldb unix-abstract /data/data/com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android/lldb/tmp platform-1474838375380.sock "lldb process:gdb-remote packets"
Debugger attached to process 927
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
Signal: SIGURG (signal SIGURG)
```

I'm not using any C++ in my app other than some compiled OpenCV code, which I haven't touched at all. I'm only using the Java wrapper for OpenCV.

The debugger frame looks like this after the first SIGURG signal:

[image: debug frame]
[image: debug frame]

I don't know if there's any other relevant information I can give about the situation since I have no idea what's going on. Please do tell me if this seems like something you have seen before and requires some additional info.

Answer (score 11):

So I couldn't find why LLDB made me wait for around a minute but I found where to disable LLDB altogether. I don't know if it was there prior to Android Studio 2.2, but you can go to Run->Edit Configurations and from the Debugger pane you can set Debug Type to Java instead of Auto.

This disables LLDB and turns things back to how they were before 2.2. However launching the app for the first time through adb still causes the splash screen to stick around for some time.